# Page-break-inside inside a div with display: table doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, page-break-inside

Since Firefox quantum my CSS don't work anymore

How can I force Firefox to print on the next page when inside elements with `display: table`?

Outside, it works fine.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

@page {
  margin: 0.1mm 12mm 5mm 12mm;
}

.page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
}

.grid {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: table-header-group;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 15mm;
  min-height: 15mm;
}

.main {
  display: table-row-group;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.footer {
  display: table-footer-group;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.footer-space {
  height: 10mm;
  min-height: 10mm;
}

.footer-fix {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <!-- GRID -->
  <div class="header">
    <!-- HEADER -->
    HEADER
  </div>
  <!-- HEADER -->
  <div class="footer">
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <div class="footer-space"></div>
    <div class="footer-fix">Footer</div>
  </div>
  <!-- FOOTER -->
  <div class="main">
    <!-- MAIN -->
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <p>1 test test test</p>
    <p>2 test test test</p>
    <p>3 test test test</p>
    <p>4 test test test</p>
    <p>5 test test test</p>
    <p>6 test test test</p>
    <p>7 test test test</p>
    <p>8 test test test</p>
    <p>9 test test test</p>
    <p>10 test test test</p>
    <div class="page-break"></div>
    <div>NEXT PAGE</div>
  </div>
  <!-- MAIN -->
</div>
<!-- GRID -->
```

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour when checking the print preview. In Chrome and Edge it works for both cases (inside and outside of the table layout). In Firefox it only works outside the table layout.